# Qt custom style: on-screen arrow buttons for scrollbars?

Tags: qt, scrollbar, qt5, qtstylesheets

[OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/) comes with a *Default* and a *Dark* theme. The *Default* theme uses the native system style (Windows 10 in my case), whereas the *Dark* theme is a custom design.

I noticed that the custom design does not have on-screen arrow buttons for scrollbars:

[image: on-screen arrow button] [image]

Don't Qt scrollbars have arrow buttons, or were they disabled by the QSS? If so, how to enable them?

Answer (score 2):

They were disabled by the qss file `Dark.qss`. This Style Sheet is hiding the arrows.

If you have the code (if not, check [this](https://github.com/jp9000/obs-studio/blob/01b274f1daab88e7ce1ed201c0d758a172eb9e0b/UI/data/themes/Dark.qss)), you can see the following lines:

```
QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal, QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal {
    border: none;
    background: none;
}

QScrollBar::left-arrow:horizontal, QScrollBar::right-arrow:horizontal, QScrollBar::add-page:horizontal, QScrollBar::sub-page:horizontal {
    border: none;
    background: none;
    color: none;
}
```

Change those properties to [customize](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qscrollbar) the QScrollBar according to your requirements.